# Apache Airflow : airflow initdb command throws = (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1292, "Incorrect datetime value:)

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, airflow

I was following this article for installing Apache-airflow with mysql DB on Ubuntu.
[Apache Airflow with MYSQL](https://bigdata-etl.com/apache-airflow-how-to-setup-airflow-to-run-multiple-dags-and-tasks-in-parallel-mode/)

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 1140, in initdb
    db.initdb(settings.RBAC)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 335, in initdb
    dag.sync_to_db()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1391, in sync_to_db
    session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1036, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 503, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 482, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2479, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2617, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2577, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1084, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '2020-01-23 11:26:36.804914+00:00' for column 'last_scheduler_run' at row 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO dag (dag_id, root_dag_id, is_paused, is_subdag, is_active, last_scheduler_run, last_pickled, last_expired, scheduler_lock, pickle_id, fileloc, owners, description, default_view, schedule_interval) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)]
[parameters: ('example_skip_dag', None, 1, 0, 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 23, 11, 26, 36, 804914, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), None, None, None, None, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/example_dags/example_skip_dag.py', 'Airflow', '', None, '{"type": "timedelta", "attrs": 
*{"seconds": 0, "days": 1, "microseconds": 0}}')]
```

Also I've added below parameters in `my.cnf` file as well:

```
[mysqld]
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
#**other variables**
default_time_zone='+00:00'
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
```

I'm trying to install Apache airflow with celery executor with MySQL
 DB.While hiing the `airflow initdb` command i'm getting above mentioned error.

Kindly help me in resolving this issues.

Thanks for the help.